# How do I define Entity Framework provider in code?

Tags: entity-framework, ms-access, jet-ef-provider

I am using the `JetEntityFrameworkProvider`. I am trying to connect to an MS Access file (it has ext `.sep` but it is indeed an Access file).

I am trying to define the connection string and provider in code, but it is not working. Before I run I get the following error:

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

I do not wish to configure the provider in the config. Surely there is a way to do this.

When I do run it (yes it will build), I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Jet OLEDB:Database' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

Context class

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    private DbConnection con = new JetConnection();

    public ProjectContext() : base(new JetConnection(""Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\Test-Project.sep'; Provider=Jet OLEDB:Database; Password=SEEME;""), true)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Entity class

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Counter")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the connection string to this.

```
public ProjectContext() : base(new JetConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Test-Project.sep'; providerName=JetEntityFrameworkProvider; Password=SEEME;"), true)
{

}
```

However, I have a new problem and a new error so I will post a new question.